# Getting started with CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

How did you get started with CouchDB?
Resources to recommend?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CouchDB [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/) is the definitive source of info. The in-progress CouchDB [book](http://books.couchdb.org/relax/) will likely replace it as the best getting started resource once its complete. For most folks, it seems the hardest part of CouchDB to grok is the map/reduce paradigm. The interactive CouchDB [simulator](http://labs.mudynamics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/icouch.html) from Mu Dynamics is an awesome learning tool for understanding the map/reduce paradigm in CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I can recommend you get a CouchDB server up and running with minimum effort by grabbing the [TurnKeyVM image](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/couchdb)

FYI - I'm also just starting to investigate it now...pretty excited, hope it does what I think it can do for me!